# String.replace(Regex) returns undefineds

Tags: javascript, regex, string

My example is paired down but I believe it communicates my problem:

I have a simple string `var data = '360–400&nbsp;'`
for sake of example:

```
data.replace('&nbsp;');
```

returns:

```
//360–400undefined
```

**Question:**  how do I make sure my output doesnt leave undefines in the string

Comment: Yeah I'm dumb I got it. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a second parameter to the [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in order to replace the matched value. If you simply want to remove the value, just pass an empty sting, `''`:

```
data.replace('&nbsp;', '');
```

The reason it was replacing the value with `undefined` was simply because the second parameter was `undefined`.

Comment: ugh. yup I'm dumb. beating my head on the desk for like 15mins on this.